# What should I ask as an applicant in a job interview?

Tags: interviewing

At the end of a job interview (at least for mid- or high-level positions), the interviewers usually give a chance for the applicant to ask any question s/he may have for the interviewers.

Does what one asks have a significant effect about the committee judgement?

If yes, what kind of questions are better to be asked?

Are the interviewers waiting to see what is the main point of interest by the applicant to consider?

Comment: see http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/11954/what-kind-of-questions-should-one-ask-in-an-interview-for-some-technical-positi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You 100% should ask questions.  What balog pal is saying is not a good idea.  The interviewers are not going to try and decide if you are just so smart that you know everything about their company.  You **NEED** to ask questions.  It is your turn to interview them.  They will be more impressed if you have detailed and specific questions to ask about their company.

Some good questions would be:

What is the work environment like at work?

Why have you stayed here, what keeps you coming back to work here?

Maybe something wasn't clear in the job description so ask about it, What would I be doing in this area?  What is a normal day like at work?

**DO RESEARCH ON THE COMPANY** You guys seemed really involved in _ _ _ _ _ How can I get involved in that?  Are you involved in that?

***Remember*** people love to talk about themselves, so ask about them, related to work and geared toward some things that would help you choose the job if you got it.

EDIT: Also a good rule of thumb I go by is to have about 5-7 good questions thought up in my head and ask 3-4 of them.  You want to have a few more thought up because it is likely that they are going to answer them already.  You also want to stay engaged while asking questions.  When they give an answer to your question ask a question that branches off their answer.  If you ask a few good questions you will leave the interview just fine.  Remember **EYE CONTACT AND FIRM HANDSHAKE** you want to start off on a good note and end on one as well.

Answer (score 3):

> Does what one asks have a significant effect about the committee
>   judgement?

IMO, If you don't have any questions about the company you are interviewing for then they could take it to mean that you aren't that interested in the company.

> what kind of questions are better to be asked?

You should ask questions that show you really want to know about the company. This will show that you are intelligent enough to want to learn enough about a company before working there.*****

***EDIT**: If you can't come up with any questions because the interviewer has really answered all of them already, you could tell the interviewer they've succeeded in already answering your questions.

Comment: hmm, i'm not sure i agree with the inverse that not having questions shows a lack of intelligence. If the company has provided a comprehensive overview that answers all of your questions before hand then i don't see that as a failure on the interviewee's part, but a huge success on the interviewers part.

Comment: @RhysW in that case, when they ask if you have any questions, tell the interviewer that they've succeeded in already answering your questions. IMO, everybody should go to a job interview with questions otherwise it is obvious that the interviewee is just interested in "a" position and not "the" position.

Comment: "Tell the interviewer they've succeeded in already answering your questions" I think that part would make a fantastic addition to your answer if you were to edit it in

Comment: I've edited the question accordingly. Thanks RhysW

Comment: oops, ..edited the answer...

Answer (score 1):

That part of the interview is *not* there as another manipulation opportunity. As an applicant you should ask question that you're genuinely interested in and need the information.   Especially whatever is relevant to make a decision on accepting an offer. But "just curious" is also a fair game.

I suggest NOT asking anything just for show.

A good interviewer will not build any conclusion of that section, as candidates may be well prepared so not need to ask. Or what is usual, just be mentally exhausted at that point. Os just shy or anything.