# Good question to ask a potential employer at a job interview?

Tags: interviewing

I'm not currently looking for a job, but this question just started rolling through my mind. When on a job interview, it is not only important to properly respond to questions, but also ask some. Would this be an appropriate question to ask: `Tell me why I should I work for you?` Granted, you may already be answering the question to `Tell me why you want to work for us?` but this is an inverse of that. How can I ask this in a way that is useful in learning about the company?

Comment: Related Question: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/11954/what-kind-of-questions-should-one-ask-in-an-interview-for-some-technical-positi?rq=1

Comment: Is it good or bad is not really the type of thing we can help with.  We can however help you ask that question in a way that will be helpful to you and explain why.

Comment: dupe of workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/12730/what-should-i-ask-as-an-applicant-in-a-job-interview ?

Comment: wow, this is almost identical to another question asked today, which was closed for being a duplicate.  [duplicate of this one](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/12730/what-should-i-ask-as-an-applicant-in-a-job-interview)

Comment: @RhysW - Asking for judgement on the question is going to be opinion based.  How can I ask it is constructive since the op knows what he wants to know and that being blunt may be a problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally speaking question `Tell me why I should work for you?` comes across with some (IMHO large) degree of arrogance on your part and to some if not all interviewers would be a turn off.

Normally if you're trying to gauge whether or not the company or this particular department is worth working for look at external reviews like Glassdoor or if you want to know about the company I'd ask:

- Do you like working for this company? And if so: Why?

This question sort of puts the ball in interviewer's court to do sort of a "sales" pitch to you about the company/department/team you're applying to and their reaction also allows you to gauge their happiness in their job and to some extent the result of an interview (if the answer basically blows you off).

Comment: Very well put. By the time we get to that part, if the candidate was a kind to put me on fire, I already tried some convincing that he should join. So that question would sound pretty dumb.

Comment: @BalogPal, are you saying that if the interviewer already gave an overview of what it's like to work at the company, that asking "Why should I want to work here?" would be sort of redundant? If that's what you mean, then that makes sense. :)

Comment: @jmort253: yeah, that's included :)

Answer (score 2):

It a question that's on every interviewee's mind, but put like that it can seem like you're not really interested.

I've found in my years a version that works for me, plus a followup:

**1. (to the interviewer): What was it about this company that made you want to join?**

Once the interviewer has answered (which is usually positive as you are asking the interviewer for their opinion) follow up with:

**2. What is it about this company that keeps you here?**

You'll soon know if they think it is really a great place to work, or the red face will speak volumes...

Comment: these are really excellent questions!

Answer (score 1):

You want to avoid asking questions that put the interviewer "on the spot" or contain ambiguity in their implication.

If you asked me  "Tell me why I should I work for you?" , it sort of sounds like "Actually I don't want to work for you"

You want questions that demonstrate clear interest on your part. Maybe "i'm the type of person who really likes teamwork and I like pair-programming, how does your firm foster this?" etc